# Recent version of Pycharm doesn't have settings option for MAC OS

Tags: python, macos, settings, pycharm

Yesterday, I downloaded the latest version of Pycharm for MAC OS at office. I am struggling so hard, so get my correct settings.

- Firstly there is no `settings` options in the latest version for MAC OS users. There are only three choices 'import settings`, 'export settings` and `default settings`.  Why I am not getting the `settings` option? See the below image for reference, this image is from my home `linux laptop`

[image]

- If you go to `default settings` -> `Editor` in MAC OS, there are very few options for changing the current settings which is so weird. I can't see anything any option for `colors & fonts`.
- I am not able to increase or decrease the `font size`. I tried all the options given in their website but none is working.

Can anyone help me? Its really affecting my flow of work!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The additional preferences you are looking for are under

```
pycharm > preferences...
```

[image]

Comment: Will check at office tomorrow and accept your answer. Already gave thumbs up :)

Comment: Thanks! Hope it helps, I have had the same problem and although I found it, it just confused me at first. :)